# Azure Powershell VSO agent task not failing for non-zero exit code

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, exit-code, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines

When putting together a release definition in VSO, adding an [Azure PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQX5H.png)
 task 
backed by a file `Script1.ps` only containing `exit 1` does not fail the step when it runs - which I would expect it to do, given that the `Continue on error` box is not checked
If I add the [PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9w1U.png) task, writing `exit 1` using the inline variant would indeed fail the step. This also comes with an 'advanced configuration option' where the `Fail on Standard Error` is checked by default.

What did I miss? How would I go about making the `Azure Powershell` fail in the same manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this code instead:

```
[Environment]::Exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The task will fail if the script throws an exception or writes to stderr stream.